# Getting content from tinyMCE with userscripts in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tinymce, greasemonkey, userscripts

My problem is trying to get the content of the Tumblr's tinymce editors with an userscript.
In firefox this works perfectly:

```
var tm = (unsafeWindow.tinyMCE) ? unsafeWindow.tinyMCE : null;  
if(tm!= null){
    var _tempcontent = tm.activeEditor.getContent();
    console.log(_tempcontent);
}
```

But in Chrome i get "undefined" and then when I revised the unsafeWindow i couldn't find the tinymce instance, while in Firefox exists.

Comment: what is undefined? the variable tm? can you check for the var tinymce? what do you get?

Comment: Yes, the variable tm is undefined because the unsafeWindow.tinyMCE neither is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although *Google Chrome* now defines `unsafeWindow` for userscripts, [it does not allow any access to the target page's javascript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10828021/331508).  It only allows access to the DOM.

To workaround, you can provide the script with a cross-browser, full-featured `unsafeWindow` -- as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10945153/331508):

```
/*--- Create a proper unsafeWindow object on browsers where it doesn't exist
    (Chrome, mainly).
    Chrome now defines unsafeWindow, but does not give it the same access to
    a page's javascript that a properly unsafe, unsafeWindow has.
    This code remedies that.
*/
var bGreasemonkeyServiceDefined     = false;

try {
    if (typeof Components.interfaces.gmIGreasemonkeyService === "object") {
        bGreasemonkeyServiceDefined = true;
    }
}
catch (err) {
    //Ignore.
}

if ( typeof unsafeWindow === "undefined"  ||  ! bGreasemonkeyServiceDefined) {
    unsafeWindow    = ( function () {
        var dummyElem   = document.createElement('p');
        dummyElem.setAttribute ('onclick', 'return window;');
        return dummyElem.onclick ();
    } ) ();
}
```

---

**OR,** you can refactor your script to use *script injection*...

```
function main () {
    //--- PUT EVERYTHING IN THIS WRAPPER FUNCTION...
    var tm = tinyMCE;
    if (tm!= null) {
        var _tempcontent = tm.activeEditor.getContent();
        console.log(_tempcontent);
    }
}

addJS_Node (null, null, main);


function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    //--- Don't error check here. if DOM not available, should throw error.
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

Comment: The two options seems to work with some tintmce demos that i found over internet, since I'm in work and the proxy settings don't let me enter to tumblr now I'll test this when I get home. Thanks for your answer.