# why isn't Chrome unsafeWindow trick supporting XMLHttpRequest send override?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I want to override `XMLHttpRequest`'s send in order to let my userscript know when data is getting updated on a page through such a request. My override code looks like this:

```
var oldSend = unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(){
    console.log("notified of XHR update");
    oldSend.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

If I inject this into the page (w/o the `unsafeWindow` references) it works fine, but I'd like to get this working from userscript scope.  `unsafeWindow` works for this in Firefox, but not in Chrome.  So I grabbed [Brock Adams' nifty trick to create a working `unsafeWindow` in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10945153/348496):

```
var bGreasemonkeyServiceDefined     = false;

try {
    if (typeof Components.interfaces.gmIGreasemonkeyService === "object") {
        bGreasemonkeyServiceDefined = true;
    }
}
catch (err) {
    //Ignore.
}

if ( typeof unsafeWindow === "undefined"  ||  ! bGreasemonkeyServiceDefined) {
    unsafeWindow    = ( function () {
        var dummyElem   = document.createElement('p');
        dummyElem.setAttribute ('onclick', 'return window;');
        return dummyElem.onclick ();
    } ) ();
}
```

However, when I combine the two nothing happens.  It all works pasted into the console, but there's neither error nor output when running this from a userscript.  Am I doing something wrong or perhaps this is beyond the capabilities of this trick?

Hmm, just tried something simpler, like: `unsafeWindow.document.title = 'testing';` and that doesn't work either, so maybe it's not specific to `XMLHttpRequest`.

I'm trying to avoid injection into the page if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
/*--- Create a proper unsafeWindow object on browsers where it doesn't exist
    (Chrome, mainly).
    Chrome now defines unsafeWindow, but does not give it the same access to
    a page's javascript that a properly unsafe, unsafeWindow has.
    This code remedies that.
*/
var bGreasemonkeyServiceDefined     = false;

try {
    if (typeof Components.interfaces.gmIGreasemonkeyService === "object") {
        bGreasemonkeyServiceDefined = true;
    }
}
catch (err) {
    //Ignore.
}

if ( typeof unsafeWindow === "undefined"  ||  ! bGreasemonkeyServiceDefined) {
    unsafeWindow    = ( function () {
        var dummyElem   = document.createElement('p');
        dummyElem.setAttribute ('onclick', 'return window;');
        return dummyElem.onclick ();
    } ) ();
}
```

followed by this:

```
unsafeWindow.document.title = 'testing';
```

Works just fine from my test userscripts.

These also work following the `unsafeWindow` trick:

```
unsafeWindow.foo = function () {
    console.log ("In foo().");
};

unsafeWindow.alert = function (s) {
    console.log ("Alert: ", s);
};
```

(On a page where the script has run, entering `foo()` in the console yields: "*In foo().*".  `alert()` does not generate a popup but prints to the console.)

I don't know why (yet) that overriding `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send` doesn't work like that from a Chrome userscript, but **I don't recommend the `unsafeWindow` approach for that anyway.**

*Inject* the override code.  Use [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage#Example) (which works on Chrome as well) to communicate between the page scope and the script scope, if you don't (or can't) inject the whole script.

Comment: brock, thx for the `postMessage()` suggestion. i was trying to avoid injecting the code, partially in response to having read your pros/cons list on the subject (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10828021/348496) --- mostly to protect the script from getting shutoff or blocked by the host site. sounds like you recommend injection regardless? i'll look at `postMessage()` and also reconsider whether i should just inject it all.

Comment: For Chrome, and this kind of thing, injection is best. `unsafeWindow` can actually get blocked just as easily as injected JS can, but you always have the upper hand, in the end, over the site. However, `unsafeWindow` opens a potential channel for malicious sites to gain elevated privileges.  Injection does not.  ... Personally, I've yet to need any but the most trivial access (and seldom that) to a page's JS.  Most practical cases where people want a script to intercept AJAX, are better served just by polling for changed content.  That can remain entirely in the safe sandbox.

Comment: if I could make things work without any injected JS at all, is that still the best option?  or is it not worth the extra hassle (debugging, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, avoiding injection (and unsafeWindow) AMAP, is always best (faster, more robust, more secure).  But avoiding that is not always possible.  If you ***truly*** need to intercept AJAX, for example, you will have to inject at least some code.