# Accessing Variables from Greasemonkey to Page & vice versa

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I have the following code in *test.js* which is run right before </body>:

```
alert('stovetop');
alert(greasy);
```

I have the following code in *test.user.js*:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';
    var greasy = 'greasy variable';
    document.title = 'greasy title';

}());
```

'stovetop' gets alerted so I know the page javascript works, and `document.title` gets changes so I know that the script javascript works. However, on the webpage I get the error:

> Error: ReferenceError: greasy is not defined Source File: /test.js

How from the webpage do I access the variable set by Greasemonkey and how about vice versa?

Comment: If you go this way, it'll only work in firefox as Chrome sandboxes userscripts.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

- Greasemonkey scripts operate in a separate scope and may also operate in a sandbox, depending on the [`@grant` settings](http://wiki.greasespot.net/@grant).
- Additionally, the question code isolates `greasy` in a function scope (as gladoscc said).
- Finally, by default, ***test.js*** will fire before the Greasemonkey script does, so it won't see any set variables, anyway.  Use [`@run-at document-start`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at) to address that.

So, given this ***test.js***, run right before `</body>`:

```
window.targetPages_GlobalVar = 'stovetop';

console.log ("On target page, local global: ", targetPages_GlobalVar);
console.log ("On target page, script global: ", gmScripts_GlobalVar);
```

Then the following will work:

**No sandbox:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Greasemonkey and target page, variable interaction
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @include     http://output.jsbin.com/esikut/*
// @run-at      document-start
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

//--- For @grant none, could also use window. instead of unsafeWindow.
unsafeWindow.gmScripts_GlobalVar = 'greasy';

console.log ("In GM script, local global: ", unsafeWindow.targetPages_GlobalVar);
console.log ("In GM script, script global: ", gmScripts_GlobalVar);

window.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    console.log ("In GM script, local global, after ready: ", unsafeWindow.targetPages_GlobalVar);
}, false);
```

**With sandbox, no function scope, `unsafeWindow`:**
==> **Important update:** [Greasemonkey changed unsafeWindow handling with version 2.0, the next sample script will not work with GM 2.0 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24720223/331508).  The other two solutions still work.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Greasemonkey and target page, variable interaction
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @include     http://output.jsbin.com/esikut/*
// @run-at      document-start
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

unsafeWindow.gmScripts_GlobalVar = 'greasy';

console.log ("In GM script, local global: ", unsafeWindow.targetPages_GlobalVar);
console.log ("In GM script, script global: ", unsafeWindow.gmScripts_GlobalVar);

window.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    console.log ("In GM script, local global, after ready: ", unsafeWindow.targetPages_GlobalVar);
}, false);
```

**With sandbox, no function scope, *Script Injection*:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Greasemonkey and target page, variable interaction
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @include     http://output.jsbin.com/esikut/*
// @run-at      document-start
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

function GM_main () {
    window.gmScripts_GlobalVar = 'greasy';

    console.log ("In GM script, local global: ", window.targetPages_GlobalVar);
    console.log ("In GM script, script global: ", window.gmScripts_GlobalVar);

    window.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        console.log ("In GM script, local global, after ready: ", window.targetPages_GlobalVar);
    }, false);
}

addJS_Node (null, null, GM_main);

function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun, runOnLoad) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    if (runOnLoad) {
        scriptNode.addEventListener ("load", runOnLoad, false);
    }
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

---

Notes:

1. You can test these script against [**this page** (output.jsbin.com/esikut/1)](http://output.jsbin.com/esikut/1).
2. With no sandbox, `unsafeWindow` and `window` are the same.
3. All of these scripts produce the same output on the console:

   ```
   In GM script, local global: undefined
   In GM script, script global: greasy
   On target page, local global: stovetop
   On target page, script global: greasy
   In GM script, local global, after ready: stovetop
   ```
4. The *Script Injection* code will work in a variety of browsers besides Firefox. `unsafeWindow` currently only works in Firefox+Greasemonkey(or Scriptish) or Chrome+Tampermonkey.

Comment: btw http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow say's its unsafe to use unsafeWindow, what would a safer alternative be in this case?

Comment: The "safer" alternative would be to either use the `@grant none` method but replace `unsafeWindow` with `window` (although they are identical when `@grant none` is in effect), **or** to use the *Script Injection* method. ... However, the risk of using `unsafeWindow` is greatly overblown -- with no real exploits reported.  As long as you aren't on a site that's actively targeting GM scripts, there should be no risk.

Comment: Can you perchance update your answer? I have a question similar to the original but it seems that things have changed in 10 years. Or should I post it as a new question?

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `greasy` is defined in the scope of the anonymous function. You cannot access `greasy` even in your userscript, unless it is part of your function. Example:

```
(function(){
    var foo = 5;
    alert(foo);
}();
alert(foo); //ERROR, because foo is undefined outside of the function.
```

Do it this way:

```
var foo = 5;
(function(){
     alert(foo);
}();
alert(foo);
```

Also, why are you putting all your code in an anonymous function and then executing it?

Comment: I just used a greasemonkey template script and it had the example code in the anonymous function. I assumed it was required for greasemonkey scripts. I moved the var declaration outside of the function and I still can't alert the variable value from the test.js script on page.

Comment: Could it be my test.js script is being run before Greasemonkey? If so how can I delay it?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
localStorage.setItem("numberOfThings", "42");

localStorage.getItem("numberOfThings");
```