# Greasemonkey script only loads with CTRL + F5?

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter, greasemonkey

I created this Greasemonkey for batch following/unfollowing *Twitter* users. The script works just fine. However, it won't always (almost never) load the first time I go to one of the pages on the include list.

For instance, if I go to [twitter.com/followers](https://twitter.com/followers), the script won't load unless I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> (which refreshes the page contents from the server).

I am not sure whether this is how Greasemonkey scripts are supposed to run, or there is something in my code that I need to change?

My GM script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Brainstack.net "YOU Follow (Beta)"
// @namespace       net.brainstack.gm
// @description     Script for automating the following of users from the Twitter Followers page
// @require         http://gm.brainstack.net/tasa/tasa.js
// @resource        tasa_CSS http://gm.brainstack.net/tasa/tasa.css
// @downloadURL     http://gm.brainstack.net/tasa/Brainstack.net_tasa.user.js
// @updateURL       http://gm.brainstack.net/tasa/Brainstack.net_tasa.meta.js
// @include         https://twitter.com/followers*
// @include         https://www.twitter.com/followers*
// @include         https://twitter.com/*/followers*
// @include         https://www.twitter.com/*/followers*
// @include         https://twitter.com/*/following*
// @include         https://www.twitter.com/*/following*
// @include         https://twitter.com/following*
// @include         https://www.twitter.com/following*
// @include         https://twitter.com/search/users?*
// @run-at          document-end
// @grant           GM_getResourceText
// @grant           GM_addStyle
// @version         1.14
// ==/UserScript==

//add CSS to head
var CSS = GM_getResourceText("tasa_CSS");
GM_addStyle(CSS);

//hook to the page load
bsnet_app_page_load();
```

---

You can [download and/or install the script at gm.brainstack.net](http://gm.brainstack.net/tasa/Brainstack.net_tasa.user.js).

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for including full code via links.  But this Q is close to "Too localized" and/or a code review. (The bulk of the code is in `tasa.js` and that's a bit much for an SO question.  Try to pare question code down to [an SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is the same type of issue covered by [I have to refresh the page for my Greasemonkey script to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024120/i-have-to-refresh-the-page-for-my-greasemonkey-script-to-run).   Read, understand, and use the techniques of that answer to "fire" your script on "new" pages.

***Additionally,*** the script code in `tasa.js` has things like:

```
var localStorageString = localStorage['bsnet_app_follower'];
if (localStorageString.length > 0){
```

which crash the script, especially on early runs.

That kind of code *should be*:

```
var localStorageString = localStorage['bsnet_app_follower'];
if (localStorageString  &&  localStorageString.length > 0){
```

---

---

There may be other issues (didn't see any at a glance; didn't debug the script either), but this is not the place for code review.

Comment: Thanks @brock. I appreciate your feedback. I will go through the other post and apply the techniques to my script. It's hard not having a peer to review my code ;-)

Comment: You're welcome and good luck.  There is [a site for code reviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).