# Detect when new tweets are loaded using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter, greasemonkey, userscripts

You know how when you scroll to the bottom of a profile page (I'm talking about a user's personal page, not the timeline), new tweets are loaded automatically. I'm writing a UserScript in which I want to execute a function every time those new tweets are loaded.

But I can't figure out a way to detect this new tweets loaded event. I assume its an AJAX request, right? So I tried the below two functions but to no avail.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    alert("Complete! New tweets loaded!");
});

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  alert("Success! New tweets loaded!");
});
```

Here's what I have so far. This works when the page is loaded at first. But it doesn't affect the tweets loaded after you scroll down.

```
// ==UserScript==

// @name            CoolScript
// @include         https://twitter.com/IJNanayakkara
// @include         https://twitter.com/IJNanayakkara/status/*
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @require         https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @version         1.0
// @license         GPL v3 or any later version (http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html)
// @grant           GM_addStyle

// ==/UserScript==

$.each($('p.js-tweet-text'), function() {
    $(this).prepend("Brought to you by ");
});
```

How can I detect loading new tweets from jQuery?

---

**Edit:**
I noticed another issue. The script doesn't run when you navigate to the page. I actually have to refresh the page. I searched and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024538/1077789). I imported that .js file to the script but I don't know which element I should actually wait for.

How can I make the script run without manual refreshing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, your code like this:

```
$.each($('p.js-tweet-text'), function() {
    $(this).prepend("Brought to you by ");
});
```

works on the static bits of the page, or from the command console, then it translates into this `waitForKeyElements` code:

```
waitForKeyElements ("p.js-tweet-text", prependToTweet);

function prependToTweet (jNode) {
    jNode.prepend("Brought to you by ");
}
```

Simple:  The selector stays the same, and the `.each()` code ports directly, except that `$(this)` is replaced by `jNode`.

---

`waitForKeyElements` handles the AJAXed elements automatically (works on scroll-down and without needing refresh).

Comment: Thanks, Brock. It works but there's a new problem. If I navigate to a new page from my profile, say to the timeline, all the tweets in there also affected by the script even though I have scoped it for only two pages using `@include`. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: No, and I don't use twitter.  Make a new question with an ***exact*** recipe for duplicating the new problem.

Comment: Oh okay. I opened a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27705455/1077789). Hopefully I'll find something that sheds some light on this. Thanks anyway :)