# waitForKeyElements AJAX request not working

Tags: ajax, tampermonkey

I am using the `waitForKeyElements` function in a `tampermonkey` userscript to check for new tweets on twitter after an AJAX request occurs while scrolling the page down. `addCustomSearchResult()` is called after the initial page load and grabs those tweets.

`addCustomSearchResult()` does not run when new tweets are loaded after the ajax call as I scroll down the page.  What am I doing wrong?

```
// @require     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle

waitForKeyElements("li.js-stream-item",addCustomSearchResult);
function addCustomSearchResult (tweet) {
    console.log('found new tweet');
}
```

Comment: What twitter page(s) are you on? Are you logged in? ...  Typically you would use selectors like `.Tweet-body` or `.Tweet`.  ... I almost never use Twitter, but I don't see any `li.js-stream-item` nodes on any Twitter pages that I checked.

Comment: Also, I don't know if [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27705455/twitter-userscript-affects-pages-other-than-the-intended-included-ones) still applies. Twitter has often been a bit screwy about how they do things.

Comment: Yes I am logged in, what nodes do you see that hold the tweets?  I'll try it with the .Tweet-body selector.  http://screencast.com/t/IiiK49J0tmYi. I don't have any classes called Tweet or Tweet-body on my pages...