# Rewriting the global alert() function doesn't work in Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, alert, tampermonkey

In Greasemonkey I can rewrite the global `alert()` function with:

```
window.alert = function() {...}
```

and it works anywhere.
But, in Tampermonkey (Chrome), it only works on it's own script.

Why? 
And could I make it work globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, that will only work in Greasemonkey sometimes.  The [grant mode](http://wiki.greasespot.net/@grant) has to be `none` -- which I recommend against.  As you have discovered, accidentally tripping that mode makes un-portable scripts -- along with other sins which are beyond the scope of this question.

To make this code work on Tampermonkey (and Greasemonkey too), use [unsafeWindow](http://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?t=74), like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant    unsafeWindow
// ==/UserScript==

unsafeWindow.alert = function() {...}
```

**Or,** use *script injection* as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13485650/331508).

---

---

The `@grant unsafeWindow` directive is for Greasemonkey -- to restore the sandbox and to allow use of `unsafeWindow`.  This lets the same script work the same way in both Tampermonkey and Greasemonkey.