# Change link target to "_self" for existing Click eventListener (which currently targets "_blank")

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener

I am writing a userscript for a website to change link targets from "_blank" to "_self".

The website's links are all handled by an EventListener on Click action, which reviews the `id` attribute for every `<a>` element to set the click URL and load it in a new tab. None of the `<a>` elements have a `href` or `target` attribute.

I would like all clicked links to load in the same tab (rather than a new tab).

Is there any way to modify link targets set by an event listener, or to simply set/override the default link target for all links on a webpage?

Comment: Anchors _wouldn't_ have a `src` attribute. `href` maybe?

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed. Yes, `href` not `src` (`href` is just set to `javascript:void` for every link on the page)

Comment: Can we see some code so I can understand your case?

Comment: The website's code is sandboxed, which is what's making this pretty difficult. But I was able to use inspector to see an EventListener on Click, which is what's setting the link behavior for the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you want to override the behavior of links that open in a new tab, you could override `window.open` as such:

```js
window.open = (open => (href => open.call(window, href, '_self')))(window.open);
```

For anchor tags with an explicit target of `_blank`, you could theoretically override the click method to force the target:

```js
window.HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.click = function() { window.open(this.href, '_self') };
```

However,  this is in fact a hacky solution and might not be the best idea to use in production.

Comment: The first line is exactly what I would be looking to do (override the default behavior of window.open). Hacky is fine, as this is just for myself and a few colleagues. But even after applying the code, the links still open in a new tab. I tried it on a vanilla page with just a link and eventListener, and it worked totally fine (opened in self), so I'm guessing the Click eventListener on this other website must call some custom link opening function?

Comment: @jm92 Look at the page's js code and ensure it's using `open`. If it indeed is, you should verify that the `window.open` in the page's context is your overriden version of the method.

Comment: Marked your answer correct, as it's exactly what I needed. The JS code is massive, but is there any way I can use inspector/console to display which function is called upon click? I'm having trouble deciphering that by reading through EventListeners in inspector.

Comment: @jm92 Maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892

Comment: Thank you! I found another question, which combined with your answer, solved the issue. Userscripts are separated from the target page, so re-declaring the open function was not enough to overwrite the default global open function. The function from this answer allowed me to inject it into the page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271997/how-to-overwrite-a-function-using-a-userscript

Answer (score 0):

you can do select your element with `document.querySelector().target = "_self"`

Comment: Unfortunately even after setting the target like that, it loads in a new tab

Comment: Do you use jQuery?

Comment: I am willing to, if it would solve the issue

Comment: try this `$("a").attr("target","_self");`, it might work

Answer (score 0):

EDIT Jan 12, 2023: there is a much better and easier way to do this, if you're using Tampermonkey.

GM_addElement allows you to do exactly what I described in the request, to insert code into actual page:

https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:GM_addElement

I used the script version, to add a function (you have to enclose it in quotes, like text).

This solution works much better with stricter websites and browsers, so you won't get CSP errors.

OLD ANSWER:

The answer to this question solved my issue:

[How to overwrite a function using a userscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271997/how-to-overwrite-a-function-using-a-userscript)

I re-wrote the open function from skara9's answer, and then inserted it with the addJS_Node function from the above question.

Userscripts are separated from the target page, hence why simply re-declaring the function was not overwriting the default global open function.