# Adding a @grant value breaks my Greasemonkey+jQuery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

When I add the @grant for GM_xmlhttpRequest, I get:

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'call'

in the jQuery file.
If I remove the grant, it works fine.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Dimi Test
// @namespace   Dimi
// @include     about:addons
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @include http://*.myDomain.*/*
// ==/UserScript==

var $J = unsafeWindow.jQuery;

$J(unsafeWindow.document).ready(function(){
    alert('Hello');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brock, I distilled the question down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See ["Error: Permission denied to access property 'handler'"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24720223/331508).

You can no longer invoke the target-page's jQuery like that.

(Note that in `@grant none` mode (the default as of GM 2), `unsafeWindow` is the same as `window`... But, then you can't use `GM_` functions.)

---

`@require` your own copy of jQuery; it will not conflict with the page's and will load faster, to boot.

Do not use `unsafeWindow` for things like this (or at all, if you can help it), and `$(document).ready()` is also almost never needed for Greasemonkey scripts.

Your (new) sample script would merely be:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Dimi Test
// @namespace   Dimi
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @include     about:addons
// @include     http://*.myDomain.*/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$("body").prepend ('<h1>Hello World!</h1>');
```

And you can then mix `GM_` functions and your instance of jQuery with no problems.

---

---

Note: The question script has `// @include about:addons`.
[Greasemonkey scripts will not work on the `about:addons` page, by design.](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules#Greaseable_schemes)

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I managed to get it going from there. Much appreciated!