# Cant get tampermonkey script working

Tags: javascript, php, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

So at first I was trying to make this script to make evony accounts by using xampp but instead now im trying to use tampermonkey but I cant seem to get any of it to work for some reason :/

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Evony account maker
// @include  http://www.user.evony.com/index.do?PageModule=ForgetPassword
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
window.location = "http://www.user.evony.com/index.do?PageModule=ForgetPassword";
var email = rpplaysevony;
var password = daxter23;
var accnumber = 0;
function createaccount(){   
document.getElementById("tab2").click()//trying to click a button with 
// the id of tab2
document.getElementById('username').value = email + accnumber + "@yahoo.com";
}
window.onload = function () { createaccount() }
```

Any help would be awesome :)
also tried

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Evony account maker
// @include  http://www.user.evony.com/index.do?PageModule=ForgetPassword
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
window.location = "http://www.user.evony.com/index.do? PageModule=ForgetPassword";
    //var email = rpplaysevony;
    //var password = daxter23;
    //var accnumber = 0;
    function createaccount(){   
    document.getElementById("tab2").click();
   // document.getElementById('username').value = email + accnumber + "@yahoo.com";
    }
    window.onload = function () { createaccount();}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  it looks like, to me, as soon as you set the window.location, it's going to ignore the rest of the script and load the page.

Comment: I am not sure that you still can access `window` object from the time you use any `@grant` function. See [How to access window (Target page) objects from a GM content script (@grant other than none)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778469/how-to-access-window-target-page-objects-from-a-gm-content-script-grant)

Comment: Im trying to make it click on a button so that the register account stuff shows up

Answer (score 0):

you've set the script to run on

```
http://www.user.evony.com/index.do?PageModule=ForgetPassword
```

your first line changes the page to

```
http://www.user.evony.com/index.doPageModule=ForgetPassword
```

the script wont run on'

```
http://www.user.evony.com/index.doPageModule=ForgetPassword
```

Hope that helps

OK - so that was a typo

where is the value of 'email' set?

edit 2 -

You have the following:

```
var email = rpplaysevony;
var password = daxter23;
```

Are `rpplaysevony` and `daxter23` supposed to be strings or do they refer to some vars you're not showing?

Comment: sorry its a typo on here on the act. code the links are the same

Comment: forgot to put it in added it now - also will the code that is correct run if theres errors?

Comment: they should be strings - even not lookin at that part whats wrong with the click? document.getElementById("tab2").click()//trying to click a button with 
// the id of tab2

Answer (score 0):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Evony account maker
// @include  http://user.evony.com/index.do?PageModule=ForgetPassword
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementById('username').value = 'rpplaysevony0@yahoo.com';
document.getElementById('pwd').value = 'daxter23';
document.getElementById('pwd2').value = 'daxter23';
document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0].firstChild.click();
```