# window.Object != Object for greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts

The following script logs `false` to the console. Does anyone know why or what benefits it brings?

From a brief glance into Greasemonkey's source code I couldn't find anything that modifies `Object`. Also looking into the `Object` it is hard to see any meaningful differences, all the functions are still native code.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test
// @namespace   test
// @include     *
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

console.log(window.Object == Object)
```

(tested on Greasemonkey & Firefox, not sure about Scriptish & Chrome, though any experiments welcome!).

[NOTE: this question is *unrelated* to the question of `{a: 2} != {a: 2}`, please read the question itself and not just glance at the title before you cast any close votes, thanks!].

Comment: You can't just simply compare Objects, as they will never be equal (different references in memory and so on) [Object comparison in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: @Justinas I'm not sure that is relevant, this one is for the object class and the other one is for instances.

Comment: it seems that `window` ain't the global object in this case, but instead references the window-object of the current page. So like two frames/windows don't share the same classes (identical, but not the same), `Object` and `window.Object` are not the same reference either. That's basic sandboxing, so that one frame/window doesn't interfere with the global variables of the other frame/window. Imagine one page would modify `Object.prototype` and all windows in your browser would get that change.

Comment: Or if all pages in your browser would share the same `location` object ;)

Comment: @Thomas Hmm good thinking, although I think that a userscript can only operate on the current page it runs on, unlike addons. In the test script there are no `@grant`s so there is no extra privilege. But perhaps something like this is still going on, I wonder where I can find the code/docs that makes this happen.

Comment: `console.log(this === window, this, window, this.window === window)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a side effect of Mozilla's current sandbox process.  Even in `@grant none` mode, Greasemonkey sandboxes scripts using [Components.utils.Sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.Sandbox) -- only with Xrays off and `wantExportHelpers` left at `false`.

So, your `window.Object == Object` is equivalent to `window.Object == this.Object`.
But: In a Greasemonkey script, `this` (the root/global this) is always a `Sandbox` object, not a `Window`.

Firefox may have a good reason for cloning `Object` like that, but I couldn't find any reference saying as much.

---

**Chrome with Tampermonkey does not do this** and `window.Object == Object` is true for Tampermonkey scripts regardless of the `@grant` setting.

Chrome also does not do sandboxing the same way.

Comment: So how would I correctly write `window.Object === Object` so that it works in GreaseMonkey?

Comment: @Aran-Fey, I don't support Greasemonkey 4+ (and there's a separate tag for it). But if `unsafeWindow` doesn't work for your *true* purpose then you would use script injection. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/25785794/331508

Comment: just wanted to point out to you that irregardless is a double negative, also not a word