# Firefox doesn't respect Object.defineProperty() from a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, tampermonkey, adblock, greasemonkey-4

I'm writing a userscript to prevent a website to set `document.body.innerHTML`, this is a typical sign of a website detecting adblock:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    console.log("Loading ...");

    Object.defineProperty(document.body, "innerHTML", {
        set: function() {
            console.log("malicious activity detected");
            throw "Don't try to fool my adblock!";
        }
    });
    console.log("Test setting document.body ...");
    try {
        document.body.innerHTML = "";
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}) ();
```

The above userscript works fine for Chrome+Tampermonkey. But its behavior on Firefox+Greasemonkey-4 is weird.

The output in console is:

> Loading ...
>   Test setting document.body ...
>   malicious activity detected
>   Don't try to fool my adblock!

So the userscript loads successfully, and the setter is successfully hooked as well. But when after loading and I try in the console:

```
document.body.innerHTML = ""
```

it just sets the `innerHTML` without throwing error, as if the hook has not been installed. I've tried all `@run-at` options, but none of them works.

---

OTAH, if I use `Object.defineProperty()` in console, then it works as expected. Therefore I conclude that Firefox doesn't respect `Object.defineProperty()` from userscript.

You can also try visiting this website: https://connectwww.com. With the above userscript installed in Tampermonkey in Chrome, the adblock-detection on the website is successfully intercepted. But the userscript doesn't work on Firefox+Greasemonkey.

**Why does Firefox *not* respect `Object.defineProperty()` from a userscript? Is there any workaround?**

### A side note:

Some well-known userscript like anti-adblock-killer also works on Chrome but not Firefox for the above testing website, I guess it's due to the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

*Greasemonkey 4* sandboxes your script even in `@grant none` mode.  <sup><sub>(That is about the only thing that *Greasemonkey 4* does better than Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey.)</sub></sup>

So your script is setting the script's scope/copy of `innerHTML`.
In Tampermonkey that is shared with the target page scope but, in Greasemonkey, the 2 scopes are more properly separated. So the page scope (and the default console) do not see the change.

In this case, I don't think [the `unsafeWindow` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778469/how-to-access-window-target-page-objects-when-grant-values-are-set) can be made to work; **you must inject the override code**.

Here is a script that works with both Greasemonkey 4+ and Tampermonkey (and should on Violentmonkey too, but I didn't test that).  It works on both Chrome and Firefox:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Overriding Target page functions can be tricky with GM 4
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant    none
// @run-at   document-start
// ==/UserScript==
/* eslint-disable no-multi-spaces */

console.log("Loading ...");

function overrideIt () {
    //-- Necessary check because of scope madness in TM, VM, etc.
    if (document.body.innerHTML) {
        Object.defineProperty (document.body, "innerHTML", {
            set: function () {
                var scopeStr = (typeof GM === "object"  &&  GM.info) ? "script" : "page";
                console.log (`Malicious activity detected - ${scopeStr} scope`);
                throw "Don't try to fool my adblock!";
            }
        } );
    }
}
overrideIt ();

if (typeof unsafeWindow === "object") {
    console.log ("unsafeWindow detected.");
    addJS_Node (null, null, overrideIt);
}

console.log ("Test setting document.body ...");
try {
    document.body.innerHTML = "";
} catch (e) {
    console.log ("Caught: ", e);
}

//-- addJS_Node is a standard(ish) function
function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun, runOnLoad) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    if (runOnLoad) {
        scriptNode.addEventListener ("load", runOnLoad, false);
    }
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```