# Intercept XMLHttpRequest from Greasemonkey script fails

Tags: xmlhttprequest, sandbox, interceptor, restriction, greasemonkey-4

I seek to manipulate the XMLHttpRequest done by a website using Greasemonkey (version 4.9 installed). Interception should be simple ([How can I intercept XMLHttpRequests from a Greasemonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/629671/12221801)) but does not work for me. Maybe things changed with newer versions of Greasemonkey?

I obviously tried the examples in the linked question, but they don't have any effect - nothing printed in the console although I have an `console.log(...)` in my customised open function.

Next, I gave `unsafeWindow` a try. It should not be needed. My userscript runs with `@grant none` and documentation ([see](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Content_Script_Injection) [here](https://wiki.greasespot.net/index.php?title=Content_Scope_Runner&oldid=7215)) says my script should run in the content scope.

With `unsafeWindow` I get an effect but it breaks XMLHttpRequest completely

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Test
// @version       1
// @include       *
// @run-at        document-start
// @grant         none
// ==/UserScript==

"use strict";

let realOpen = unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open

console.log("Real: " + realOpen)

unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
  console.log("Called for " + this + " with URL: " + arguments[0])

  //call original
  return realOpen.apply(this, arguments)
};

window.addEventListener ("load", function() {
  console.log ("Page loaded");
});

console.log("Unsafe: ", unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open.toString())
console.log("Normal: ", XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open.toString())
```

This gives following output in console:

```
Real: function open() {
    [native code]
}

Unsafe:  function() {
    console.log("Called for " + this + " with URL: " + arguments[0])

    //call original
    return realOpen.apply(this, arguments)
  }

Normal:  function open(method, url) {
    // only include method and url parameters so the function length is set properly
    if (arguments.length >= 2) {
      let newUrl = new URL(arguments[1], document.location.href);
      arguments[1] = newUrl.toString();
    }
    return origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
  }

==> Page loaded
```

As mentioned, function of XMLHttpRequest is broken. When I use the Firefox developer console to have a further look I get this

```
>> window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open
Restricted {  }
```

Any properties set on `window` (like `window.foobar = "foobar"`) do not exist in console, but those set on `unsafeWindow` do. I assume this has to do with Greasemonkey's sandboxing.

Why are there two versions of XMLHttpRequest even when I use `@grant none`? Why is my custom function restricted? Can I avoid that? Why does it work without problems when I install event listener on window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Next, I gave unsafeWindow a try. It should not be needed. My userscript runs with @grant none and documentation (see here) says my script should run in the content scope.

This is wrong for Greasemonkey 4 as stated in its [announcement](https://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-script-authors.html):

> Due to the more limited abilities that the new extension system gives us, we are currently unable to make @grant none scripts work in the same way.  Most importantly, they have a different connection to unsafeWindow.  For the short term at least, it's a good idea to adopt [cloneInto and exportFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts).

See also this other question [Firefox doesn't respect Object.defineProperty() from a Greasemonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489964/firefox-doesnt-respect-object-defineproperty-from-a-greasemonkey-script)

This change explain the observations, but no idea why adding listener to window work.