# Javascript with Grease Monkey : @grant messes up Youtube API

Tags: javascript, youtube

I'm using GM to write a custom script for a website. The script adds an embed Youtube player to the page, so I'm calling the Youtube API. Here is the beginning of the code :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @author       mens
// @match        http://thewebsite.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

///////////// YOUTUBE

// API
var player;
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// API loaded
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function()
{
    console.log("API loaded");
}
```

With this code, everything works fine. The first few lines call the API, when it's loaded it fires `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`, then later on my script generates the `player`.

You will notice that `@grant` is set to `none`. The problem is when I change this line, even the slightest. I use `GM_getResourceURL` to access external files (like graphics).

So when I set :

```
// @grant        GM_getResourceURL
```

...the API doesn't work anymore : `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` is never called !

From what I gathered in the GM documentation, `@grant none` is the default mode that means maximum access to all APIs used in the code. When changing `@grant` more restrictions may appear... I think that's part of the problem but I have no idea how to work with it.

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Have you considered using `@require` in place of inserting a `script` tag?

Comment: yes I tried it, then I get an error : `Uncaught TypeError: YT.Player is not a function`... it seems the YT object used to create the player is not fully loaded

Comment: question whose answer will solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485122/accessing-variables-from-greasemonkey-to-page-vice-versa/13485650 (but technically isn't a duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

So the trick was simple (but quite mysterious) : I changed `window` to `unsafeWindow` by renaming the function :

```
unsafeWindow.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function()
{
    console.log("API loaded");
}
```

From the GM doc :

> unsafeWindow
>
> The unsafeWindow object provides full access to the pages javascript functions and variables.

It seems any `@grant` other than `none` puts the `window` object into a sandbox with limited access from external APIs. I'm still unsure how to set these restrictions correctly, but `unsafeWindow` bypass them completely.

Comment: I take it you've read http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow and understand the implications?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
// API loaded
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function()
{
    console.log("API loaded");
}
```

do this

```
function apiReady() {
    console.log("API loaded");
}
exportFunction(apiReady, unsafeWindow, {defineAs: "onYouTubeIframeAPIReady"});
```

See [Mozilla docs](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/) for explanation of exportFunction

However, I'm not 100% convinced yet myself that this is any more "secure" (in greasemonkey) than using `unsafeWindow` directly

> From what I gathered in the GM documentation, @grant none is the default mode that means maximum access to all APIs used in the code.

This is incorrect. What `@grant none` does is explicitly turn off **ALL** greasemonkey API's (the *GM** functions) and run the script without a sandbox, as there is no possibility of rogue websites using greasemonkey against you.