# Access Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey variables from the browser console?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, browser-console

This is example of code from the userscript:

```
var ExampleObj = {
  somevar1:'value1',
  somevar2:'value2',
  somevar3:'value3',
  somefunction1:function(){
    //do sth
  },
  somefunction2:function(){
    //do sth else
  }
}
```

And when I try to call my functions from script: everything is OK, but
I can't get access from browser console:

> (ReferenceError: ExampleObj is not defined)

My Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey settings (Metadata):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     [this is my secret]
// @version  1
// @run-at document-end
// @include [this is my secret]
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==
```

The script works; I just need access to those functions from the browser console.

Answer (score 6):

In `@grant none` mode, scripts still operate in a protected-ish scope.  Place your object in the global scope by changing:

```
var ExampleObj = {
```

To:

```
window.ExampleObj = {
```

Then you'll be able to see and use that object.  (Note that the target web page can also see and use it.)

See "[Accessing Variables from Greasemonkey to Page & vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485122/accessing-variables-from-greasemonkey-to-page-vice-versa)" for more information and for scenarios when `@grant` is not none.