# Greasemonkey - access in page window Javascript variable from userscript?

Tags: javascript, userscripts, greasemonkey-4

I'm trying to access a javascript variable loaded in the page from a Greasemonkey script.
I tried the var name directly , or using `window.varname` (which works in the console), but neither of them load in the greasemonkey script (the window variable is `undefined`).

I tried `run-at document-end` and using setTimeout around the function, neither of those work.

Is there a specific way required to do this, or did I run into a bug for a specific page ?

[Accessing Variables from Greasemonkey to Page & vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485122/accessing-variables-from-greasemonkey-to-page-vice-versa) asked this question as the second part of the question, but I didn't see a clear answer. (I would comment under that question, but I don't have the credits).

Answer (score 2):

Using unsafeWindow can access page variables

`unsafeWindow.varname`

https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/2700

https://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow