# JavaScript check if browser extension is installed for Chrome, Firefox and Opera

Tags: javascript, firefox, opera

I want to show custom bar ( notification like: Install our plugin. ) on our site **if extension is not installed** for Chrome, Firefox and Opera. None will be displayed if extension is installed.

**The idea is**:
1. User visits our site and a bar with message appears - "Hey, install our extensions".
2. User clicks on install and extension is installed. No need for the user to open it.
3. User visit our site again and the bar does not appear again as the extension is installed.
**We talk only for installation check, not cookies**.

So far I was able to find solutions only for Chrome: http://blog.kotowicz.net/2012/02/intro-to-chrome-addons-hacking.html
and Firefox: http://webdevwonders.com/detecting-firefox-add-ons/
Opera is never mentioned.

Is there a way to do it for Opera, based on the idea of checking for a local resource which is part of the extension: 
chrome-extension://--Extension ID--/blank.gif
Firefox chrome://firebug/content/blank.gif

Or else:
**Is there a simple way to check if extension is installed for Chrome, Firefox and Opera?**

Comment: It's quite easy if the extension is willing to cooperate

Comment: Or if that extension leaves traceable info like some unique element or attributes in DOM.

Comment: Or if that extension leaves something in the global scope - that's what I meant by cooperation

Comment: If you're trying to autodetect adblock, you could give it a honeypot - or just test the presence of the real ads you've added.

Comment: So, what is the extension you're trying to detect?

Comment: The extension is just a shell that displays a webpage. Nothing to do with AdBlock.
@Jan Dvorak How to cooperate? I want for the page that shows the bar to know is the extension is installed despite of that it is ever opened.

Comment: @user1990249 if the bar is added to the dom, it should be easy to find it there from outside the extension.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak I've updated the question with the user story. I hope the idea get clearer now.<br />
I search for connection from the browsers page with the extension not the other way around.

Comment: @user1990249 why not let the extension advertise its presence to the document, if the document wants to know whether the extension is present?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if user has a third party Chrome extension installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897925/check-if-user-has-a-third-party-chrome-extension-installed)

Answer (score 4):

If the extension is willing to cooperate, it could advertise its presence to the document easily. For example:

---

<strike>The extension could do</strike>

```
window.$$myExt = ...
```

Then you can detect the extension by

```
if(typeOf $$myExt !== 'undefined'){...
```

(or any variation thereof)

Obtaining the page `window` is [somewhat tricky at least](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622145/how-can-i-mimic-greasemonkey-firefoxs-unsafewindow-functionality-in-chrome)

---

The extension could do

```
document.body.classList.add("myExt-visited")
```

Then you could detect the extension by

```
if(document.body.classList.contains("myExt-visited")){...
```

---

The extension could do

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='myExt-toolbar'>..."
// or $('body').append("<div id='myExt-toolbar'>...");
```

then you could detect the extension by

```
if(document.getElementByID("myExt-toolbar")){...
// or if($("#myExt-toolbar").length){...
```

---

alternatively, you could do

```
<div id="myExt-replacement">
   ...
```

and the extension would do

```
var replacement = document.getElementByID("myExt-replacement");
replacement && replacement.remove();
```

---

or you could do

```
function onMyExtExists(){
  ...
}
```

and the extension would do

```
onMyExtExists && onMyExtExists();
```

Comment: Well, this is obviously the only one possible solution as in Opera the browser js can't check in an extension is installed.

I hope I can write back with detailed solution later.

Comment: Where in the extension architecture would `window.$$myExt = ...` go?

Comment: @bgadoci as soon as it wants to be detectable. That is, as soon as possible, because the extension detection cannot run before the extension makes itself visible.

Comment: The 'window' object in an extension is not the same 'window' as the website. They cannot communicate via that channel.

Comment: @geedew would `unsafeWindow` work for that purpose? If not, what would?

Comment: @geedew struck out. Should I remove the paragraph completely?