# Detect if browser extension is installed for Opera

Tags: cross-browser, add-on, browser-extension, opera-extension

I have created browser extension/add-on for Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE using `Crossrider framework`
Now since Crossrider does not provide support for Opera, I have created a native extension for the same.
My problem is how to detect if a user(using Opera), visiting our website, has the extension installed or not ?

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398548/javascript-check-if-browser-extension-is-installed-for-chrome-firefox-and-opera) is answered. Is there any better option?

Or any simple way to check(**crossbrowser**) if an extension is installed or not so that I don't have to use `Crossrider.API`?

Or is there anything similar to [window.navigator.plugins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.plugins) for extensions?

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate with your page using simple `content script` for your domain only using `window.postMessage` function.

**Content script code:**

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  if (event.source !== window) return;  // We only accept messages from ourselves
  switch (event.data.type) {
    case 'get_info': window.postMessage({type: "info", browser: 'opera'}, "*"); break;
  }
}, false);
```

**Your page code:**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    switch (event.data.type) {
      case 'info': console.log(`browser is ${event.data.browser}`); break;
    }
  });
  window.postMessage({type: "get_info"}, "*");    
});
```