# Changing PHP.ini using htaccess on a Server

Tags: php, .htaccess, browscap

I am trying to use PHP's built-in function **[get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)**. I followed the instructions in  [this useful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036956/browscap-ini-directive-not-set), but I'm still getting the error

> browscap ini directive not set.

I downloaded the php_browscap.ini file and moved it into the same directory as my .htaccess file, so that its location is **home/hostname/subdomain/php_browscap.ini** Since I do not have access to my **php.ini** file, I am trying to edit the browscap property using .htaccess. This is what I entered:

```
php_value browscap home/hostname/subdomain/php_browscap.ini
```

I don't know if it matters, but below that there's some Rewrite Engine code.

As forementioned, I am still getting the error above. What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a phpinfo() to understand your PHP runtime config.  If your system is configure as "CGI/FastCGI" then it is probably running suPHP as the PHP initiator.  <strike>In this case you can specify your own php.ini file.  By default suPHP looks in the script directory but you can override this by the following directive in your .htaccess file:</strike>

> ```
> suPHP_ConfigPath (expects a path name)
> ```
>
> This option tells mod_suphp which path to pass on to the PHP-interpreter (by setting the PHPRC environment variable).  Do *NOT* refer to a file but to the directory the file resists in.
>
> E.g.: If you want to use "/path/to/server/config/php.ini", use "suPHP_Config/path/to/server/config".
>
> If you don't use this option, PHP will use its compiled in default path.
>
> Also you must use a properly formed path in your browsercap directive e.g.

```
browscap="/home/hostname/subdomain/php_browscap.ini"
```

(Note the leading **/**)

## Addendum

I've just check and the Dreamhost shared hosting plan uses suEXEC. With suEXEC you can normally override the php.ini patch by copying the system php.ini (phpinfo() tells you where to find this) into a private directory, say **_private** as well as the browsercap.ini then adding

```
SetEnv PHPRC /home/hostname/_private
```

to your .htaccess file. If this doesn't work then the issue is specific to Dreamhost's suEXEC config and you need to ask this Q on http://discussion.dreamhost.com/

Answer (score 4):

The [`browscap`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.browscap) PHP value has a changeable mode of [`PHP_INI_SYSTEM`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) meaning it can only be set in php.ini or httpd.conf (not .htaccess).

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential problems here.

1. Perhaps your host does not allow you to override ini settings in the .htaccess file.
2. Maybe browscap does not like the path you have provided. Try:

   ```
   php_value browscap /home/hostname/subdomain/php_browscap.ini
   ```

   And ensure that permissions on that file allow the web user to read it.

Comment: DreamHost have documentation for this very problem at http://wiki.dreamhost.com/PHP.ini and web user is the system use that the web server (for example Apache) runs as. On Debian this use would be `www-data`.

Comment: @Treffynnon, Dreamhost offers a range of hosting plans. If you read your reference, it is clear that this relates to the VPS offerings.  [This wiki reference](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php/Suexec) would imply that Dreamhost uses suEXEC and not suPHP as its wrapper.

Comment: @TerryE sure. The OP did not state their plan so there isn't anything to go on. There is no reason why it could not have been a VPS.

Comment: Sure, I agree with your point.  It's unclear.  I've gotten into the habit of asking this Q upfront or nearly so, because my working assumption is that if they're talking htaccess then they're running on a shared hosting plan.  If you've got access to a vhost config then you should avoid using htaccess and even disable it if practical.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a shared hosting and do not have access to the system php.ini then you can use the following standalone replacement of php's native "get_browser()" implementation.

https://github.com/garetjax/phpbrowscap