# get_browser(); function is not working properly

Tags: php

I am working on PHP 5.4.12 and I was trying to use `get_browser();` function.
But it is not working at all.
I am getting the following error:

`"Warning: get_browser(): browscap ini directive not set in C:\wamp\www\myfirstfile.php on line 4"`

I first used `browscap.ini` present on my PC, then download one named `php_browscap.ini`, but both didn't work.

I am using wamp as my localhost. I set the location of browscap file in `php.ini` file:

```
[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
;browscap = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php_browscap.ini"
```

Still it gives me that error I mentioned above.

My code:

```
<?php
$browser = get_browser(null,true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Comment: what about this: $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036956/browscap-ini-directive-not-set

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You never enabled the option:

```
;browscap = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php_browscap.ini"
^---- comment/disable
```

Remove the `;`.

Comment: Don't forget to restart the web server, and also check phpinfo() to make sure you edited the CORRECT .ini file. There can be many of them. phpinfo will tell you which one(s) were used.

Comment: Thanks alot Mar B :) there were two php.ini files and i edited the wrong one. my program works now. thanku :)

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
wget http://browscap.org/stream?q=Lite_PHP_BrowsCapINI -O /etc/php/7.1/mods-available/browscap.ini
```

Restart your server