# Why doesn't work the get_browser function? (I configured in php.ini)

Tags: php, browser, browscap

I have a wamp64 server on my computer. 
I'd like to use the get_browser function with php, I downloaded the latest browscap.ini (for php, not for asp), I put into this folder: 
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\extra
and after that I changed the php.ini browscap row. I tried this:
browscap = "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/extra/php_browscap.ini"
and this:
browscap = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\extra\php_browscap.ini"
and this
browscap = "\extra\php_browscap.ini"
etc...
Yes, I restarted my wampserver yes, my filname is the mentioned filename yes, this is the correct folder... 
What might be the problem? 
my php code is shown below:

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
```

the error message is:
Warning: get_browser(): browscap ini directive not set in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [browscap ini directive not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036956/browscap-ini-directive-not-set)

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036956/browscap-ini-directive-not-set