# How can I find out which browser a user is using?

Tags: javascript, browser-detection

I would like to show a pop-up telling the user if their browser is outdated. How can I find out what browser they are using in javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function BrowserDetection() {

        if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {

            var ffversion = new Number(RegExp.$1) ;     
        }

        else if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {

            var ieversion = new Number(RegExp.$1);       
        }

        else if (/Chrome[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            var chromeversion = new Number(RegExp.$1);
            // capture x.x portion and store as a number

        }
        else if (/Opera[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {

            var oprversion = new Number(RegExp.$1) 
        }
        else if (/Safari[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            var safariversion = new Number(RegExp.$1);


        }

        }
```

Then after finding the version, u will compare and display popup according to your need.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this browser detection script:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't detect *browsers*, detect *browser features*. There's a good discussion on Stack Overflow already:

[Browser detection versus feature detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294586/browser-detection-versus-feature-detection)

Comment: This isn't an answser to the question.  Who care's what people think.