# How to detect Firefox mobile with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, mobile, user-agent

I'm using the following code to detect whether the browser being used on my mobile site matches a certain crieteria:

```
var isiPhone = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null;
if (isiPhone){ alert ('iphone');
```

but if I attempt to do this for Firefox / Mozilla, I can't get it to work. I've tried:

```
var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.match(/Mozilla/i != null);
```

and

```
var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox/i != null);
```

I visited whatismyuseragent.com and got the following:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Android;Linux armv7l; rv6.0) Gecko/20110811 Gecko Firefox/6.0 Fennec/6.0
```

Any idea how I properly detect this? I need to write some firefox specific code.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, you might consider doing feature detection instead (http://ejohn.org/blog/future-proofing-javascript-libraries/). Also see this other question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294586/browser-detection-versus-feature-detection

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `navigator.userAgent` to detect the browser and `navigator.platform` to detect the current platform.

**To Detect Firefox:**

```
var is_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
```

**To Detect Android:**

```
var is_android = navigator.platform.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1;
```

**To Detect Both:**

```
if(is_firefox && is_android)
    //Do Work
```

I would recommend using something like **[modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)** to avoid browser detection and focus on feature detection.

Comment: OP is asking to detect the mobile version. How will this differ between mobile and non-mobile?

Comment: Should be fixed - added platform detection in there as well.

Comment: Sniffing for "firefox" is almost certainly the wrong thing to do.   You probably want to look for "gecko/" instead.  Sadly, looking for "gecko" doesn't work because of WebKit-based browsers often including that string in the UA string...

Comment: It's a pity Firefox Mobile doesn't support touch events, otherwise you could just do a simple ("ontouchstart" in window) and be done with it. Now you need to do browser sniffing and we're all back in the nineties again :(

Comment: Firefox now returns "Linux armv7l" as the platform instead of android, so this won't work.

You can however check for "android" and "firefox" in the userAgent, which includes both, e.g:

"Mozilla/5.0 (Android 7.0; Mobile; rv:50.0) Gecko/50.0 Firefox/50.0"

Answer (score 6):

```
var isFirefox = /Android.+Firefox\//.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

Answer (score 2):

The mobile version of Firefox is Fennec, so just search for that:

```
var is_Firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('fennec') > -1;
```

Comment: not working...
this is the output of navigator:
"Mozilla/5.0 (Android 8.0.0; Mobile; rv:64.0) Gecko/64.0 Firefox/64.0"

Answer (score 1):

None of the above functions were working for me, specifically buriwoy was detecting either android or firefox, this version of his function works:

```
function detectAndroidFirefox () {
   var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
   if(agent.indexOf('firefox') >= 0){
     if(agent.indexOf("android") >= 0){
       return true;    
     } else{
       return false;
     }
   } else{
     return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check from user agent if it's contain firefox or android, for this maybe you need some code with regex

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This detects Firefox on Android plain and simple:

```
isFxAndroid = /^Linux a/.test(navigator.oscpu);
```

Or the same thing more modern with `startsWith`:

```
isFxAndroid = navigator.oscpu.startsWith("Linux a");
```

How it works:
`if (navigator.oscpu) { /* I'm Firefox */ }` 
is a well known way to detect Mozilla browsers (Firefox), other browsers return `undefined`.
According to the HTML spec, Gecko browsers (Firefox) **must** return a string for `navigator.oscpu`:
*If the navigator compatibility mode is Gecko, then the user agent must also support the following partial interface*
 https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/system-state.html#concept-navigator-compatibility-mode

Firefox on Android returns for`navigator.oscpu` something like `Linux armv71` or `Linux aarch64`.
 Firefox on Linux Desktop always returns `Linux x86_64`; this string is frozen for many years (regardless of the actual CPU).
 So you get no Desktop Firefox with the proposed query.

You can test your browser's return value for `navigator.oscpu` here:
 http://jeka.info/test/navigator.html

Answer (score -1):

Rion's answer doesn't work (at least anymore), because navigator.platform doesn't return Android, it returns Linux.

I wrote a function which seems to work:

```
function detectAndroidFirefox () {
   var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
   return (agent.indexOf('firefox') + agent.indexOf("android")) >= 0;
}
```

Thought maybe someone will need this.