# Detect Ckeditor failure

Tags: javascript, ios, ckeditor

I suppose this is a more specific version of my recent question [Browser-sniffing alternative for bugs/misbehaviors (NOT lack of features)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718673/browser-sniffing-alternative-for-bugs-misbehaviors-not-lack-of-features).

CKEditor is known not to work on certain clients like iOS Safari. Rather than use hackish browser detection, is there a way to see at runtime whether ckeditor will work on the current browser so that I can not load it or fall back to an alternative in case it won't?

Comment: Apparently the latest beta is expected to work in iOS 5 if that helps: http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_3.6.2_released

Comment: I saw that, which actiually inspired my question. I'm looking forward to that, but I imagine it will be a while before most of my users upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CKEditor.env.isCompatible](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.env.html#.isCompatible) and that way you can know exactly if a browser version is supported or not (for example iOS 5 is supported in 3.6.2 as Clive has mentioned)

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot. This looks like the answer.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor has the [`instanceReady()`](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=16787&start=0) event. That might help - if you can afford to wait for that to fire, and have a timeout of sorts in case it doesn't.

There doesn't seem to be a `onerror` event in CKEditor. The list of main events is [here](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery).