# Soundcloud custom player not playing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, soundcloud

I have installed soundcloud's custom HTML 5 player from [github](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player) onto [my site](http://iamnatesmithen.com/soundcloud/examples/sc-player-minimal.html) for testing purposes. I have noticed this player does not work in the firefox browser. I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: $.browser is undefined 


 if ($.browser.msie) {
  return '<object height="100%" width="100%" id="' + engineId + '"     classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" data="' + swf + '">'+
'<param name="movie" value="' + swf + '" />'+
   '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />'+
    '</object>';
      } else {
       return '<object height="100%" width="100%" id="' + engineId + '">'+
         '<embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="100%" width="100%" src="' + swf + '"            type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="' + engineId + '" />'+'</object>';
    }
    };
```

Does firefox require a flash player? has anyone come across this problem before ?

Comment: I'm getting an error in firefox: `TypeError: $.browser is undefined
http://iamnatesmithen.com/soundcloud/js/sc-player.js
Line 174`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.browser` is a [deprecated jQuery property](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) and was removed as of jQuery version 1.9 (the same version you're including on your page).

You must include a version of jQuery (< 1.9) on your page in order to use the `browser` property.

I think this is also a good opportunity to point out that, generally, [feature detection is preferred over browser sniffing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294586/browser-detection-versus-feature-detection).