# CGridView disable ajax update on IE<10

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, yii

Can I disable ajax Update in CGridView only on Internet Explorer < 10?

Comment: Browser detection is [commonly frowned upon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294586/browser-detection-versus-feature-detection). What is your aim here? Perhaps feature detection is a better way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get IE version manualy and add use in widget:

```
$isIE10 = !preg_match('/(?i)msie [1-9]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        .................
        'ajaxUpdate' => ($isIE10?'id':false),
        .................
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use jQuery's [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) to detect it.

```
var ua = $.browser;
if ( ua.msie && parseInt(ua.version, 10) < 10 ) {
  alert( "Disable AJAX!" );
}
```

*Note: Example untested, build from examples on linked site*.