# How to detect browsers other than Safari for iPhone web app?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, browser-detection

I'm able to detect chrome browser other than **safari** with

> user_agent =  request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].downcase
>
> user_agent.include?("crios")

But, how to detect other browsers like **Dolphin**

Dolphin browser user_agent also showing same as Safari. Is there any other way to detect browsers.

Comment: We have a bunch of duplicates for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do this? It's usually not a good idea.

Feature detection is usually a much better way to go. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294586/browser-detection-versus-feature-detection/1294765#1294765) for a good explanation.