# What's the difference between feature detection, feature inference, and using the UA string

Tags: javascript, user-agent, browser-feature-detection

I was asked this question in a job interview recently, specifically around Javascript.  I was wondering the proper response.

What exactly is the difference between `feature detection`, `feature inference`, and using the  `User agent` string?

Comment: All of these can be easily looked up on the Internet, no? That should be the first step and what is unclear *then* might make a good Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Also so many resources when Googling `feature detection vs. user agent`, like [Browser detection versus feature detection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1294586)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[Feature detection](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/feature-browser-detection/) checks a feature for existence, e.g.:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

Feature [inference](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9781449328092/12dot-browser-detection/id2784208) checks for a feature just like feature detection, but uses another function because it *assumes* it will also exist, e.g.:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName) {
    element = document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Checking the [UA string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) is an old practice and should not be used anymore. You keep changing the UA checks and never benefit from newly implemented features, e.g.:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 7") > -1){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Feature detection: actually checking that the feature exists

`if('localStorage' in window)`

Feature inference: if x exists, we can assume that y exists

```
if('localStorage' in window){
   window.sessionStorage.setItem("this-should-exist-too", 1);
}
```

If you rely on the user agent, then you would have to have a map that browser X supports feature Y

Answer (score 1):

Feature detection is attempting to determine if a feature exists. For example, if the user's browser supports LocalStorage or the geolocation APIs.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) { 
    // geolocation possible.. do some stuff
}
```

Feature inference is assuming that because you've detected one feature that you can use other features. For example if you detect the geolocation API maybe you'd assume your user is on a modern browser and so now LocalStorage is available. **It's usually bad to assume** so you're much better off just using feature detection for each feature you want to take advantage of, and have a fallback strategy in place in the event a feature isn't available. Even if a user has a modern browser with geolocation doesn't mean they're going to allow your app to use it so plan accordingly.

User agent string is just reading the stupid little string that each browser sends along and then you can compare that string with some known browsers you're targeting. Generally this is a super old way of doing things and is easily spoofed so you'd have to have a very specific reason to want to go that route (maybe in a load testing environment or something). See the wiki on the topic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

You would access it in javascript similar to:

```
navigator.userAgent
```