# IE version Without conditional comments in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser, browser-detection

I know how to test an ie version using the [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). But, I found out a good and clean way to do it, by testing a javascript method and check if it's supported or not, like:

```
if(  document.addEventListener  ){
    alert("you got IE9 or greater");
}
```

But, I don't know how to test it if it's an specific version (like, I want to do something if it's **IE8**, but not if it's **IE7** or **IE9** nor other version.

I could use [James Panolsey's solution](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/detect-ie-in-js-using-conditional-comments/)

```
var ie = (function(){

    var undef,
        v = 3,
        div = document.createElement('div'),
        all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');

    while (
        div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',
        all[0]
    );

    return v > 4 ? v : undef;

}());
```

But it does test using Conditional Comments.

---

**Why not Conditional Comments?** Because of the `Standards mode`. As Microsoft states in their [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and in the [dev center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), they do **NOT** support it in their new versions:

> Important  As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no
>   longer supported by standards mode. Use feature detection to provide
>   effective fallback strategies for website features that aren't
>   supported by the browser. For more info about standards mode, see
>   Defining Document Compatibility.

---

Testing by a valid Method is more efficient in my POV, But I don't know how to do it in a way to specific the version ... ("Using **this** you can test for **that** version"). The only one that I know is the above one that I used as example. Is there others methods that I could use to test it? or not?

Comment: If you only need to test for a specific version that *does* support conditional comments, and ignore all newer versions, then you can use conditional comments just fine. Otherwise, just use feature detection as in your `addEventListener` example.

Comment: Have a look at http://modernizr.com/

Comment: test for different things, like for canvas <= ie9

Comment: @BoltClock I needed to test if it's ie for a function and if it's ie >= 11 for other. I just don't know where to look to find when some methods started being supported. so I could use them to test for specific functions. I just know the `addEventListener` atm. @pc-shooter said to test for canvas for example, that is a good one, but I want more, and don't know any nor where to look.

Comment: @MichelAyres - Look for the actual features you need.  Don't try to guess at the browser based upon something or another being true.  This is a fragile mess that the web community has been breaking free of for the past 10 years.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher What do you mean by "Don't try to guess at the browser based upon something or another being true." (it's about the `if` being used to detect the browser?) and also "This is a fragile mess that the web community has been breaking free of for the past 10 years" ?

Comment: @MichelAyres - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294586/browser-detection-versus-feature-detection

Answer (score 0):

While feature detection can be very useful, and is sometimes the quickest way to distinguish between supportive and non-supportive browser versions, detecting IE and its versions is actually a piece of cake:

```
var uA = navigator.userAgent;
var browser = null;
var ieVersion = null;
var htmlTag = document.documentElement;

if (uA.indexOf('MSIE 6') >= 0) {
    browser = 'IE';
    ieVersion = 6;
}
if (uA.indexOf('MSIE 7') >= 0) {
    browser = 'IE';
    ieVersion = 7;
}
if (document.documentMode) { // as of IE8; strictly IE proprietary 
    browser = 'IE';
    ieVersion = document.documentMode;
}

// Using it can be done like this: 
if (browser == 'IE' && ieVersion == 11)
    htmlTag.className += ' ie11';
```

.
That's all you need. You're catching higher IEs in lower Modes/Views as well with this script, including Compatibility ~.

Comment: While this could be helpful, you should emphasize a bit more that this doesn't actually detect the browser *version*, but just the browser *mode*. That may be what people want - but it may not. (For example, maybe they want to tell people, "Hey; You are in IE9 mode, but you have IE11!")

Comment: @AndrewBarber: That's true in itself. But I would think the OP has a more sophisticated objective than that.

Comment: I hope so, too; but just in case not - and for the others who will find this via Google; just to make the (potentially minor) difference known. That is definitely *the* way to detect documentMode, though. A lot less fragile and weird than previous things for versions.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Actually, I don't think one can tell IE versions from modes/views. An IE11 in IE8 mode carries/sends out the uA of IE8. The original IE8 uA, without any 'marking' that it is actually IE11 in IE8 mode/view.

Comment: Correct; you can't. Which is why I suggested adding the clarification. :)