# how to check the browser using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: jquery, html

how to check the browser **$.browser.mozilla** is not working , Even IE returns true for this

Comment: check this: http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/2013/01/16/jquery-1-9-is-out-and-browser-has-been-removed-a-fast-workaround/

Comment: You may want to consider doing feature detection instead - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294586/browser-detection-versus-feature-detection

Comment: try this: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the jQuery browser plugin for the above code to work. The detailed documentation is available here

[jQuery Browser Plugin](http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/)

After this you can simply use

```
$.browser.name
```

to get the name of the browser.

Comment: @Banarjee , Tq It worked for me , We Can get Versions Using **$.browser.version**