# Check the IE Browser with iBrowser Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need  a if(condition) to verify the browser,

```
if(iBrowser==1)
{
Code for IE}
else {
code for chrome/safari}
```

will this function works?
is there any **iBrowser** object in javascript to **check for IE Browsers**

Comment: Why browser sniffing?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294586/browser-detection-versus-feature-detection)

Comment: IE detection in JS... see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/check-if-user-is-using-ie-with-jquery)

Comment: i am using Ext Js Framework where Ext.isIE is working fine for IE 9 and below, but for IE 11 its not behaving what is Expected. so instead of calling a function and returning some value then putting condition(i.e if(getIEVersion()=="IE11"){}) is there anyway directly checking like iBrowser ==1( verified in IE browser) will it work?

Comment: That's probably because IE11, contrary to popular belief, is actually fairly standards compliant, [so it fairly drastically changed it's User Agent string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx#ie11) (chiefly the dropping of `MSIE`) so things that would normally be worked around actually work as designed.  As mentioned in the first couple of comments, _feature_ detection is a much better approach these days than _browser_ detection.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    // Opera 8.0+ 
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    // At least Safari 3+
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;              // Chrome 1+
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; //
```

Check this link 
[How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)