# Brower detection in JavaScript (Internet Explorer)

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, user-agent

I am trying to detect internet explorer using ua.match, but this code is not working. Does anyone know why?
(it works for other browers)

```
ua.match(/.*;MSIE (\.?\d+);.*/g)
```

Below is the code that works for Safari

```
ua.match(/.*Safari\/(\.?\d+).*/g)
```

Comment: Could you explain *why* you want to do this?  It's much easier and considered better practice to use feature detection (can this browser do ....?)  See here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294586/browser-detection-versus-feature-detection

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: @Archer the program simply returns the browser type of users, like this

    `if (ua.match(/.*;MSIE (\.?\d+);.*/g) != null) return PLATFORM_TYPE.msie;`

Comment: @MohamedAbbas I don't have problem with the compiling, but it returns 'undefined' brower type(which means the query should be wrong)

Comment: Yes, I understand fully what it is for.  I'm asking *why* you want to do this as there may well be a much better way (for both you and the user).

Answer (score 2):

IE 11 doesn't provide `MSIE`, it provides `Trident`. You should consider it;

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
if(ua.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || ua.indexOf("Trident") > -1)
{
    console.log("IE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from explorer ver 7 to 11, this one covers

```
if ( (navigator.appName == 'Netscape' && navigator.userAgent.search('Trident') != -1) || (ua.indexOf("msie") != -1) || (ua.indexOf('msie ')))
```